# Liferay 6.0 not responding

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm having a strange issue with my (i admit) very old liferay. Sometime yesterday morning my system broke down and doesn't start up again. I have no idea why it broke down.

Now when I restart my liferay again according to the logfile it starts fine. But when I try to acces the page via browser all I get is inifite loading. No log messages, no exceptions, no timeout, nothing. This all was Liferay 6.0.5 and JBoss 5.

I then downloaded a Liferay 6.0.6 bundle with Tomcat 6 and connected it to my oracle db. Same behavior. Next thing I did was not using an oracle connection so liferay used its built-in memory DB. And voila, startup worked immediatly. reconnecting to oracle results in failure again. I tried this liferay-tomcat bundle with all needed themes and portlets.

Then I undeployed all custom webapps and startet again and suddenly my log showed this message: `No theme found for specified theme id <MY_CUSTOM_THEME>. Returning the default theme.`

So the request must reach liferay somehow. Sadly the browser still doesn't show anything.

I'm short on ideas so I'm grateful for any help. Btw: I'm planning to relaunch with liferay 6.2 and an other db schema in couple of weeks, so a dirty workaround would totaly be enough for me.

Thinking out of the box: Is it possible to export all data from my database as sql inserts, etc and import them into liferays memory db? I know the memory db is not build for production use, but since it's only a couple of weeks I might give it a shot.

EDIT: I switched back to my jboss 5 and liferay 6.0 setting. I just noticed another strange thing. When I type a non-existent like liferays default community url (not configured in my particular portal instance) I see this message in my log `Current URL /de/web/guest/home generates exception: null`
. So apparently the illigal requests are recognized but legal requests are not served.

Thanks guys and regards. Sebastian

Comment: Then I undeployed all custom webapps and started again and suddenly my log showed this message: `No theme found for specified theme id <MY_CUSTOM_THEME>. Returning the default theme` It means you don't have such theme deployed.

Comment: When I type a non-existent like liferays default community url (not configured in my particular portal instance) I see this message in my log `Current URL /de/web/guest/home generates exception: null`. Which means the page / layout you are trying doesn't exist in your portal.

Comment: Can you show the logs generating on startup?

Comment: The logs don't show any unusual information. Anyway I solved it ths morning. Semms like it wasn't a problem with liferay itself but with the DB user. I copied all tables from my liferay schema into another und connected to the new schema. That solved it. But thanks for your help.